# Declare a class inside a function in dart

Tags: dart

I'm building a library for an API that has hundreds of API functions and result types.
For this reason, I made a simple generation script that should create all these types from a definition file.

This is how it was in javascript :

```
const params = parseTypes();
const api = {}
for (const classParams of params) {
    class VirtualClass{
        className = classParams.name;
        classType = classParams.type;
    }
    api[classParams.name] = VirtualClass;
}
```

Which worked fine for its purpose but when I tried to implement the same strategy in Dart I couldn't declare a class inside a function. doing the following

```
void main() {
  class A{
  }
}
```

gives a lot of red lines and errors

```
Error: Expected an identifier, but got 'class'.
  class A{
  ^^^^^
```

Is there a way to implement the same idea in Dart?

Comment: Why do you think it's necessary to do a nested class?

Comment: each class has many functions that do different thing based on the classParams variable (vastly different) classes were the easiest, most straight forward solution I found

Comment: Why do they have to be *nested*?

Comment: because they are created dynamically from a txt file (each line = class).
How else would I create all of them (they are 1200 classes)

Comment: Then classes are not the way to go. Use maps and define methods that operate on the map.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing currently but I wanted to avoid redesigning the library (it was originally in Javascript)

Answer (score 4):

Dart does not allow classes to be declared inside functions.
I'm not sure if the "same idea" can be implemented some other way, but if you can explain what you are trying to achieve it might be possible to find a different design which does that.

Comment: that's a shame. basically each class has a send and receive method and multiple properties that are very different based on data from the txt file they are generated from. the API sends bytes and I create a new class instance based on the bytes and fill the properties with said bytes based on the receive function